# tensorflow:Callback method `on_train_batch_end` is slow compared to the batch time

Tags: tensorflow, keras, conv-neural-network

I am trying to create a CNN model using RandomSearch but its very slow and pops this error `tensorflow:Callback method on_train_batch_end is slow compared to the batch time`
I am running my code in google colab with hardware acceleration set on gpu
this is my code

```
def model_builder(hp):
    model=Sequential([
        Conv2D(filters=hp.Int('conv_1_filter',min_value=32,max_value=128,step=32),
               kernel_size=hp.Int('conv_1_filter',min_value=2,max_value=3,step=1),
               activation='relu',
               padding='same',
               input_shape=(200,200,3)),
        MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2,2),strides=(2,2)),
        
        Conv2D(filters=hp.Int('conv_2_filter',min_value=32,max_value=128,step=32),
               kernel_size=hp.Int('conv_2_filter',min_value=2,max_value=3,step=1),
               padding='same',
               activation='relu'),
        MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2,2),strides=(2,2)),
        
        Flatten(),
        
        Dense(units=hp.Int('dense_1_units',min_value=32,max_value=512,step=128),
              activation='relu'),
        
        Dense(units=10,
              activation='softmax')
               
    ])
    
    model.compile(optimizer=Adam(hp.Choice('learning_rate',values=[1e-1,1e-3,3e-2])),
                  loss='sparse_categorical_crossentropy',
                  metrics=['accuracy'])
    return model
```

then RandomSearch and Fit

```
tuner=RandomSearch(model_builder,
                   objective='val_accuracy',
                   max_trials=2,
                   directory='projects',
                   project_name='Hypercars CNN'
                  )
tuner.search(X_train,Y_train,epochs=2,validation_split=0.2)
```

Answer (score 14, accepted):

This is caused when other operations which run at the end of each batch consumes more time than the batch itself.
It could be that you have really small batches i.e. any operation that is slower in comparison to your original batches.

`Increasing the batch size` should solve this. Alternatively, you can `use_multiprocessing = True` in `model.fit()` and select the appropriate number of workers to generate your training batches more efficiently - but this only works for datasets that use a generator or `keras.utils.Sequence`.

Two threads talking about this issue:

1. [Thread 1](https://github.com/keras-team/keras/issues/5008)
2. [Thread 2](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/37876)

Comment: use_mutiprocessing = True

Answer (score 2):

`use_multiprocessing = True` can work in removing that warning but another warning pops up relating using multiprocessing in tf2.